# Convert Date time format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert `Aug/14/2014`  to `2014-08-14` but can't get it to working and throws below error. Could someone please suggest.

```
 Update test
    set UserDATE =convert(nvarchar(10), cast(UserDATE as datetime),105)
```

> Error: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: well, the `105` format is `dd-mm-yyyy`, so no surprises it doesn't work

Comment: try casting it into Date instead of nvarchar. Cast both of them into Date and then check.

Comment: what is the type of UserDATE , if it's a DateTime then you won't need 'cast'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't understand that date format, so the `cast` will fail to parse it.

Convert it to the format `'Aug 14 2014'` which you can use format 109 to parse.

The format `yyyy-mm-dd` has the code 120.

```
update
  test
set
  UserDATE = convert(
    nvarchar(10),
    convert(datetime, replace(UserDATE, '/', ' '), 109),
    120
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the slashing with spaces and using style 100 for the conversion to date:

```
Update test 
    set UserDATE = convert(nvarchar(10), convert(date, replace(UserDate, '/', ' '), 100), 105)
```

However, if you are going to store dates as strings -- which I don't recommend -- then use an ISO standard format:  YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD.  In SQL Server, that would be format 112, 120, or 121, not 105.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error due to `UserDATE` date format.

 Remove `/` to get the correct date format.

```
cast(replace(UserDATE, '/', ' ') as datetime)
```

If you want to have date in `yyyy-mm-dd` use `120` instead of `105`.

```
Update test  
set UserDATE =convert(nvarchar(10), cast(replace(UserDATE, '/', ' ') as datetime),120)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Brandy Tech's comment 105 is wrong style. In fact there is no suitable style for Aug/14/2014.

So, your choices are:

1. Change the code where you are capturing 'Aug/14/2015' to capture as 'Aug 14, 2015' and then use style 107.
2. If #1 is not possible for some reason, you might have to string manipulation and convert 'Aug/14/2015' to 'Aug 14, 2015' and then use style 107

Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx